# What does the Eclipse Plug-ins View mean when it lists a plugin as 'disabled'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

While configuring a target platform for an RCP application I've noticed that some of the plugins I've added are listed as 'disabled'. Indeed, if I try to add them as dependencies in the manifest editor they don't show up in the suggested list. The particular plugins I'm looking at are various versions of the same plugin. I have several plugins that require different versions of that plugin. The plugins that have the dependency and the dependency itself are both third party so reducing the complexity of the dependency chain isn't my first choice.

Does anyone know what Eclipse is telling me when it lists those plugins as disabled?

Comment: I ran into this trouble as part of an upgrade process to a newer version of the eclipse platform. During that process, I also tried to convert over to using software sites instead of directories to formulate my target platform since that seemed like it should involve less manual filtering of plugins. So, it is possible that it's a quirk in p2 update site processing versus directory processing.

Answer (score 1):

> I have several plugins that require different versions of that plugin.

If those plugins are singletons (very likely) then Eclipse only activates one of them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3994281/150166)'s a good explanation why.

Comment: The plugins causing me trouble are versions of org.antlr.runtime, specifically versions 3.0.0, 3.2.0 and 3.4.0. Based on your suggestion, I checked their manifests and they are not marked as singletons. Seemed like a good guess though.